# Is it possible to have images next to .adoc files in the pages folder?

Tags: asciidoc, antora

The structure of the family directories, as outlined in the [docs](https://docs.antora.org/antora/2.3/family-directories/) requires every image to be placed inside the `images` directory. However, the OptaPlanner documentation contains both images and asciidoc files in the same directory per chapter. Please see the directory structure below:

https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-docs/src/main/asciidoc

Changing the current structure is undesired due to existing references from external repositories (breaking backward compatibility).

Is there a way of configuring Antora to pick up images from the `pages` directory and its subdirectories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The best-practices answer: Antora requires a specific directory structure and you have to adopt it.

You can adjust the Asciidoc markup to achieve this goal:

```
image::./relative/path/to/image.jpg[]
```

However, doing so could break your compatibility.

Antora 3 (currently in alpha) will provide symlink support, so you could create symlinks in the `images` folder that point to the images within the `pages` folder. Once that is in place, you can refer to those images like any other image in the `images` folder.

With Antora 3, you also could write an extension that locates images within the `pages` folder and add them to the contentCatalog as if they had been in the `images` folder. That would be notably more effort.